# Getting Firebase Realtime Database Value By Child

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm developing an application that has a chat page.
I'm using Firebase realtime database and my chat structure like this:
[image]

I'm getting new messages as below:

```
fireBuddyChats = firebase.database().ref('/buddychats');
this.fireBuddyChats.child(this.currentUserId)
        .child(this.buddy.uid)
        .orderByKey()
        .limitToLast(topMsgCount)
        .on('value', (snapshot) => {          
          this.buddyMessages = [];
          let temp = snapshot.val();
          for(var tempKey in temp) {
            this.buddyMessages.push(temp[tempKey]);
          }                            
        this.events.publish('newmessage');
    }
```

I'm listening 'newmessage' event to show new message in chat page.
The problem is: While i chatting somebody, if another friend sends any message, database trigger (I mentioned above) runs and chat page shows another friend's messages. I think it shouldn't be triggered because the "this.buddy.uid" is different. What i'm missing? Is there any suggestion?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe to prevent this you can add a conditional statement above to check if the user (the current user is talking to) actually has the uid of "this.buddy.uid".  So maybe for the code you could possibly include somewhere:

```
if (socket.uid == this.buddy.uid).then
```

This should prevent other users from joining/adding themselves onto the real-time database conversation as it is checking if the user constantly.

Hopefully this helps.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. I thought this solution. Actually, i asked if i might be doing something wrong about Firebase realtime database.